# Writing fails to MicroSD

Tags: android, storage, sd-card

I have a 16 gb Class 10 Ridata MicroSD card I bought on December which I use on my Galaxy Y phone. At first, it was working fine and fast. Now when I write to it, often times I get "Write Delay Failed" or "Can't write to file" errors. What's more, the fuller my MicroSD is, the faster it shows that error. I tried running chkdsk on the thing but there wasn't anything faulty found. I'm frustrated with these errors. Does my memory card have a bad sector or something? How can I confirm it? That's the only thing I can think of now, if I take into account that maybe when the file is being written to a bad sector, then it the write fails.

Can I still fix my MicroSD? Warranty's out. I bought this in a reputable gadgets shop.

PS: Reading from the card is still working awesome though.

Comment: Is the the phone writing to the card or your computer?

Comment: It sounds like your running into the lifetime write limits of the MicroSD card.  If thats the case there is nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with some USB flash drives. I was trying to make them boot-able and they weren't taking the boot sector. After may re-formats I used a Linux LIVECD ([knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html), [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php)) and cleared the partition table of the flash drive. I used `cfdisk /dev/sda` where *sda* is the first drive found by the system, followed by *sdb*.

I did this on a PC with no hardrive installed to ensure that I didn't bork my system.

Aftwords I formatted it in any PC with windows. You may need to format it in the Phone.  Additionally, you may have to add a partition in the Linux LIVECD after a reboot.

**`Obligatory warning`: This will remove any data stored on the flash drive**